# BLTouch not probing all points and motors making really loud noises since rebuild of latest Marlin (new hot end installed and BLTouch)

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, e3d-v6, skr-mini-e3, e3d

Please listen to [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF6AD.jpg), which illustrates the issue, with the sound on.

[Link to `configuration.h` and `configuration_adv.h`](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqArba8YeDDe8wqAjjjqbDsrVboa?e=CWL8B5)

- Machine Ender 3 Pro,
- New E3Dv6 hotend on a BMG Wind (all has been working and printing PLA, PETG, and TPU fine until I printed a mount and re-added my BLTouch).
- SKR Mini E3 1.2 mainboard.

I have rebuilt my firmware after installing a new hotend/direct drive onto my Ender 3 Pro (BMG Wind).

Firstly, the motors have become really noisy if you note the point where the nozzle moves to the middle of the bed in the linked video to do the first probe you can hear the motors making very loud noises, it does the first couple of probes in the middle of the bed which seem fine then moves to the bottom left of the bed to start the leveling procedure. Please also note the motors going from the center of the bed to the left bottom are back to their normal noise.

It then starts the leveling it probes point 1 out of 25 and seems fine, moved to point 2 again probes then the z rises and on the screen, I get a message "endstops z".

I have had all working with precompiled firmware with the stock hotend and BLTouch but as I have added a new hot end and direct drive wanted to start with a fresh marlin build. this is the result.

If I remove the BLTouch and manually level the steppers are still noisy but all work fine and I can print, I'm just trying to understand how the motors have become so noisy in certain motions, (the z-axis is always a bit noisier than normal but the other motors have been fine except when traveling really fast in certain combinations of directions).

Also, for the life of me, I cannot get this thing to probe properly - like I say it was fine with BTT's SKR E3 mini BLTouch precompiled `firmware.bin` - but I can't get into that to examine the contents, I must have some of the settings wrong.

Can anyone please suggest anything to help? I have googled all night and watched numerous videos but have had no luck at all.

By the way, the new extruder and hot end work fine and after manually leveling the bed I have had some good prints, I just added a mount for the BLTouch so I could have that working as well (I have lost some build space due to the new hotend so the bed is set in Marlin to 210 x 215. this works fine. Also, excuse the wiring I want this working before I tidy all of the wires up, again all works with the wiring as it is until I re-flash the firmware).

Comment: Hi John and welcome to SE.3DP. FWIW, this 3D Printing site [supports embedded youtube videos](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/4762), so if you upload the video to youtube then you would be able to embed the video into your post, rather than having people click an external link